# Keep radio buttons checked on view change

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application

I'm completely new to this topic.
My task is to write a spa with changing views. The values in my form fields and the checked radio buttons should appear even if you go back to the page. Basically i want to pass my values into a factory and be able to reuse them.

My question: How do i keep my radio buttons checked, if i review my view?

*index.html*

```
    <div class="container">
        <div ng-view ng-controller="Controller"</div>
    </div>
```

*page1.html*

```
    <a href="#!page2">page2</a>
```

*page2.html*

```
<form name="formname" action="" method="GET" class="mod mod-form" data-t-name="Form">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <p style="font-family:frutiger45_light, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 1rem">form of address</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">                                      
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="radio radio--inline">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio__control" name="AnredeVN" ng-model="PersonendatenVN1.value1" value="1" > 
                        <span class="radio__label">
                            Mrs.
                        </span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio radio--inline">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio__control" name="AnredeVN" ng-model="PersonendatenVN2.value2" value="2"><span class="radio__label">
                            Mr.
                        </span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </fieldset>
    </form>
<a href="#!page1">page</a>
```

*angular*

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);myApp.config(["$routeProvider","$locationProvider",function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when("/", {
    templateUrl : "views/page1.html"
})
.when("/Personendaten VN", {
    templateUrl : "views/page2.html"
})myApp.factory('passFormFields',function(){
return { value :''};
});
```

myApp.controller("PersonendatenController",function($scope,passFormFields){

```
$scope.PersonendatenVN1= passFormFields;
$scope.PersonendatenVN2= passFormFields;
});
```

This works fine if you check one radio button. When changing the view to page1 and back to page2 the radio button is still checked.
But if you check the other button and return to the page the first is checked again.

Any ideas how to fix that?
(code suggestions and tipps and tricks are welcome too)

Answer (score 0):

I think You are missing this

```
$scope.PersonendatenVN1.value1= passFormFields;
$scope.PersonendatenVN2.value2= passFormFields;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use same model variable for the radio button.

You need to use service for accessing the data between controllers.

```
myApp.service('passFormFields',function(){
   this.params = {};
});
```

when the value is changed set to the service using watch

```
$scope.$watch('PersonendatenVN1', function(newval, oldval){
passFormFields.params = newval;
})
```

and in the page load get it like

```
 $scope.PersonendatenVN1 = passFormFields.params;
```